# submit form via JS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have created a chrome extension which send a form to GTmetrix.
This is the html code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>GTmetrix Analyzer</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>GTmetrix Analyzer</h1>
    <button id="checkPage">Check this page now!</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

This is the JS file:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    console.log("f")

  var checkPageButton = document.getElementById('checkPage');
  checkPageButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log("f")
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
      d = document;

      var f = d.createElement('form');
      f.action = 'http://gtmetrix.com/analyze.html?bm';
      f.method = 'post';
      var i = d.createElement('input');
      i.type = '';
      i.name = 'url';
      i.value = tab.url;
      f.appendChild(i);
      d.body.appendChild(f);
      f.submit();
      console.log("a")
      console.log(f)

    });

  }, false);
}, false);
```

I added the console.log events in order make sure that the code is executed, however, I expect the html to present the submitted form, including the response. The issue is that I only get the tab url added to the html when I click on the button due to(d.body.appendChild(f);)  so I am not sure why I can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this another approach of **`d.body.appendchild(f)`**:

`document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(f)`;

or have a null checker like this:

```
if ( document.body != null )
 { 
    document.body.appendChild(element); 
 }
```